# Input validation (do-while loop) malfunctioning

Tags: java, validation, input, while-loop

```
===== CS302 TOOL BOX =====
T > COIN TOSS SIMULATOR
G > GRADE ESTIMATOR
C > COLOR CHALLENGE
Q > QUIT
Type code letter for your choices: h
Invalid selection. Please try agian: 
t
Invalid selection. Please try agian: 
T
```

^that is what I get when I run the program and give it an incorrect guess. The loop was made to validate the user input, so it is completely failing. Any ideas on what I've done wrong? Thanks for your time!

```
}

    System.out.println("===== CS302 TOOL BOX =====");
    System.out.println("T > COIN TOSS SIMULATOR");
    System.out.println("G > GRADE ESTIMATOR");
    System.out.println("C > COLOR CHALLENGE");
    System.out.println("Q > QUIT");
    System.out.print("Type code letter for your choices: ");
    boolean code_letter;
    String code_choice = scanner.next();
    do {
        if (code_choice.toUpperCase().equals("Q")
                || (code_choice.toUpperCase()).equals("C")
                || (code_choice.toUpperCase()).equals("G")
                || (code_choice.toUpperCase()).equals("T")) {
            code_letter = true;
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try agian: ");
            code_letter = false;
            scanner.next();
        }
    } while (!(code_letter));

    {

        System.out.println("you did it?");
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Please do not replace your question with junk text after you get your answer.  Leave the question for future readers to learn from.

Comment: If an answer has helped you, it is polite to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the `code_choice` variable inside your `do-while` loop, otherwise *the variable will not get re-initialized for every iteration of the loop before conditional test*.

```
String code_choice = scanner.next();
```

like this

```
//declared it outside to take care of the scope
String code_choice = null;
    do {
        //initialize it every time before you perform the conditional test.
        //This increases the readability!
        code_choice = scanner.next();
        if (code_choice.toUpperCase().equals("Q")
                || (code_choice.toUpperCase()).equals("C")
                || (code_choice.toUpperCase()).equals("G")
                || (code_choice.toUpperCase()).equals("T")) {
            code_letter = true;
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try agian: ");
            code_letter = false;
        }
    } while (!(code_letter));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

just try..

put your

```
scanner.next()
```

before the if, remove the curly-braces that surround the

```
System.out.println("you did it?");
```

lastly your while... change it to ..

```
while(code_letter !=  true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming scanner (lowercase S) is a Scanner object? Please include ALL of the related code next time or else it's very difficult to debug the issues.

The main problem you have is in the line in the else condition. scanner.next() doesn't do anything. You'll need to do:

```
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid selection. Please try agian: ");
    code_letter = false;
    code_choice = scanner.next(); // This needs to be modified
}
```

That should get it working.